# How to print function's output as a vector?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have to create a function called vast that prints leap years between year1 and year2 as a vector.

So this is the code I have been using:

```
vast <- function(year1,year2) {
  year <- year1
  for(year in year1:year2) {
    if(((year%%4==0)&(year%%100!= 0))|(year%%400==0))
    vast <- print(year)
  }
}
```

When I use vast(2000,2010), it should give (2000,2004,2008) as a vector that can be saved into x, but instead I get:

```
x <- vast(2000,2010)
[1] 2000
[1] 2004
[1] 2008
x
NULL
```

So the x is empty. I feel so stupid but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the values at the end of the function. You can explicitly use `return` to do that or the last line in the function is automatically returned.

Also comparison operators are vectorised so you can do

```
vast <- function(year1,year2){
  year <- year1 : year2
  leap_year <- year[(year %%4 == 0 & year %% 100 != 0) | (year %% 400 == 0)]
  return(leap_year)
}
```

then call `vast`

```
x <- vast(2000,2010)
x
#[1] 2000 2004 2008
```

You can add a `print(leap_year)` statement in the function if you want to print the years.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the return() function if you want to have the value out of the function. Here is possible solution for your code:

```
vast <- function(year1,year2){
  vast <- c()
  year <- year1
  for(year in year1:year2){
    if(((year%%4==0)&(year%%100!= 0))|(year%%400==0)){
      vast <- c(vast, year)
    }
  }
  return(vast)
}

x <- vast(2000,2010)
x
```

Comment: It's no needed. You can delete the i = 1 line and also ++i line. I have updated my  code

Comment: if you use vectorization in R, you get the code from @RonakShah